# Completely remove virtual disks with diskpart (list volume still shows them)

Tags: windows, diskpart, virtual-disk, vhdx

I'm creating a lot of differencing disks for my project and deleting them after some time.

I use "detach vdisk" command, they disappear from disk management but they are not completely removed...

When i use "list vdisk" command there is a huge list with all the virtual disks ever attached:
[image]

I couldn't find a way to clear this and I have no idea if it will impact performance at some point.
Does anyone know where all this info is stored and how to remove it?

Is there any way to completely remove a virtual disk so it won't show up in this list after?

Comment: Restart the Virtual Disk service (vds.exe). You may have to restart diskpart to see the effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry if this is an dumb answer, but you have restarted the windows machine?

I have tried creating an Parent disk with a child differencing disk like you have, and i can see them with list vdisk, but the list is empty after reboot.

For your second question, i would use either disk management or powershell to manage VHDs.

Dismount-Vhd will 'detach' the vhd and you can remove it with Remove-Item